# Rails gem is absent after Capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to deploy my application on Ubuntu server. I installed Nginx/Phusion Passenger and deployed my application with Capistrano, it works (I can open URL and look at project). I use RVM and only one version of Ruby I installed before (ruby 2.0.0p643). But when I go to my project folder and try to execute 'rails c production' I get the following error:

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I don't understand what does mean this error - I uploaded my Rails app, it works, I see rendered HTML page, but this error tells me something other :). Also, if I execute 'gem list' I get the following list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.9.9)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

I don't see 'rails' in this list, but as I said before my application works!!! Please, tell me, what I did wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My application works, how it can work without Rails ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use,

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

This is because your are using `rvm` which bundles the gems inside namespace (inside `/vendor` on production) which won't be available outside the bundle context.

**Note:**

Gems can be installed outside the bundler context with Capistrano (http://paulgoscicki.com/archives/2011/10/tell-bundler-to-install-gems-globally-when-using-capistrano/)

Comment: Thanks it works! How can I remove need to add 'bundle exec' to each command? Thanks !

Comment: adding `bundle exec` actually good as it uses the gems specified in the `gemfile` without which your command will use global gems. If you reluctant to use `bundle exec` then you need to install gem  to global namespace which can be accessible outside the bundler context.

Comment: ok thanks! But how I can install gems globally? On my local machine I use RVM & Ruby, but I don't execute 'bundle exec' for each command

Comment: You can install gems globally with Capistrano, check this out http://paulgoscicki.com/archives/2011/10/tell-bundler-to-install-gems-globally-when-using-capistrano/